# String to integer in AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to convert a string to an integer in the controller

```
parseInt( $scope.date)
```

But i have to do this in the view

```
<span data-ng-show="item.date">{{ item.date | hbdatetime }}</span>
```

In the view itself i have to convert the date ( which i am getting as a string ) to an integer so that i can filter with hbdatetime .

I am trying something like this

```
// <data-ng-show="item.date">parseInt{{ item.date | hbdatetime }}</span>
```

Please help in angular way

Comment: Is hbdatetime a custom filter of yours? If so, do any conversions there. Lastly, you should be able to run any valid JS expression within the curly braces, ie: {{ parseInt(item.date) | hbdatetime }}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to place the function call to *parseInt* inside the expression:

```
<span data-ng-show="item.date">{{ parseInt(item.date) | hbdatetime }}</span>
```

Angular will pass the value of *item.date* to the function and then apply the filter to the return value.

You might want to consider writing your own filter that can handle a string as input.

Comment: I have created one more filter and i am doing this in the filter itself ,thanks